# Python type comparision

Tags: python, instance, dynamic-typing

Ok, so I have a list of tuples containing a three values `(code, value, unit)`

when I'm to use this I need to check if a value is an str, a list or a matrix. (or check if list and then check if list again)

My question is simply should I do like this, or is there some better way?

```
for code, value, unit in tuples:
    if isinstance(value, str): 
        # Do for this item
    elif isinstance(value, collections.Iterable):
        # Do for each item
        for x in value:
             if isinstance(x, str):
                  # Do for this item
             elif isinstance(x, collections.Iterable):
                  # Do for each item
                  for x in value:
                      # ...
             else:
                  raise Exception
    else:
        raise Exception
```

Comment: The body of the outer `for` loop is rather confusing.  Shouldn't there be `x` instead of `value` in the first line?  And shouldn't the inner loop be something like `for y in x`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is to avoid mixing types like this, but if you're stuck with it then what you've written is fine except I'd only check for the `str` instance. If it isn't a string or an iterable then you'll get a more appropriate exception anyway so no need to do it yourself.

```
for (code,value,unit) in tuples:
    if isinstance(value,str): 
        #Do for this item
    else:
        #Do for each item
        for x in value:
             if isinstance(value,str):
                  #Do for this item
             else:
                  #Do for each item
                  for x in value:
```

Answer (score 2):

This works but every time you call `isinstance`, you should ask yourself "can I add a method to `value` instead?" That would change the code into:

```
for (code,value,unit) in tuples:
    value.doSomething(code, unit)
```

For this to work, you'll have to wrap types like `str` and lists in helper types that implement `doSomething()`

Comment: I wont actually do anything on the value, but assign value(s) to an excelsheet. I believe it is easier for me to do like Duncan says.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to your approach is to factor out this code into a more general generator function (assuming Python 2.x):

```
def flatten(x):
    if isinstance(x, basestring):
        yield x
    else:
        for y in x:
            for z in flatten(y):
                yield y
```

(This also incorporates the simplifications suggested and explained in [Duncan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11612542/279627).)

Now, your code becomes very simple and readable:

```
for code, value, unit in tuples:
    for v in flatten(value):
        # whatever
```

Factoring the code out also helps to deal with this data structure at several places in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the tuples and catch any exceptions. Don't look before you jump :)

Comment: I think you mean, _Easier to Ask forgiveness than Permission_ :)

Answer (score 0):

Recursion will help.

```
def processvalue(value):
  if isinstance(value, list): # string is type Iterable (thanks @sven)
    for x in value:
      processvalue(value)
  else:
    # Do your processing of string or matrices or whatever.


# Test each the value in each tuple.
for (code, value, unit) in tuples:
  processvalue(value)
```

This is a neater way of dealing with nested structures, and will also give you the ability to process abitrary depths.

Comment: In this case I know that 2dimensional arrays are the largest, and i have to index them, which might be harder using this approach

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by indexing them.